# Conda VE errors when installing "tensorflow"

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

When trying to setup tensorflow in a conda VE and I was getting a ton of errors. I have checked both here and online and it seems to be related to GPU and VM versions of tensorflow **which I didnt install**.

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

I am also getting a multitude of errors such as:

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
```

and

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
```

and also

```
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

**All at the same time**

I have tried deleting and re-creating my conda enviroment and I have gotten the same error.

Details:
Python version 3.7

```
conda activate tensorflow
pip install python=3.7
```

Tensorflow version 2.6 (CPU version not GPU)

Comment: Could you post whole output? That's just warnings. Info message that TF uses AVX AVX2 in some operations and can't find nvcuda.dll for GPU.
Just use TF on CPU.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614262/how-to-install-cpu-version-of-tensorflow-using-conda You might be trying to install the gpu version of tensorflow without access to the gpu.

Comment: I belive the error may be from TF GPU version trying to be installed automaticaly instead of the default CPU version. Ill will try look even further into it but thats what im guessing the problem is comming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How was it fixed:**
Issue was fixed by installing CPU version of tensorflow manualy. https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/TensorFlow-Installation-CPU-version-1129/

**Issue:**
It was automaticaly pip installing the CUDA GPU version of tensorflow and hence wasnt working with my none CUDA enabled GPU.

If you get errors such as:

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

or

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

This may too, be your issue